# Postprocessing of CFD results in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, fluid-dynamics

I was trying to perform computational fluid dynamics (CFD) post-processing in *Mathematica* after solving primitive variables from Navier-Stokes equation, mainly $(u,v)$, $(Px,Py)$. Since I am not an expert with the finite difference and *NDSolve* functionality of *Mathematica*, I used FORTRAN to perform numerical simulation.

The objective is to generate streamlines and vorticity from $u$ and $v$ values in *Mathematica*.

I looked online and found this link : http://bugman123.com/FluidMotion/index.html where vorticity and streamlines calculations were demonstrated.

I tried cloning the same code using

```
u = Import["F:\\Lid_Driven_Cavit\\Run_Max_Interations\\u_final.dat", "CSV"];

v = Import["F:\\Lid_Driven_Cavit\\Run_Max_Interations\\v_final.dat","CSV"];

(* u and v represents velocity components in x and y directions     
   respectively *)

n = Dimensions[u, 1];

dx = 1/(n - 1);

dy = dx;

\[Psi]= \[Integral]u dx= \[Integral]v dy
\[Omega]= \[PartialD]v/dx-\[PartialD]u/dy


psi = Table[0, {n - 1}, {n - 1}]; Do[
psi[[i, j]] =psi[[i, j - 1]] + dx (u[[i + 1, j - 1]] + u[[i + 1, j]])/2,{j, 2, n - 1}, {i, 1, n - 1}];

psi = ListInterpolation[psi, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

ContourPlot[psi[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
PlotRange -> All, ContourShading -> False, 
Contours -> {-0.08, -0.077,-0.07, -0.06, -0.045, -0.025, -0.01,-0.0025, 0,-8*^-6, 2*^-6, 3*^-5, 8*^-5, 1*^-4, 3*^-4, 6*^-4, 9*^-4},
ContourStyle -> Table[{Hue[2 (1 - x)/3]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/16}]]
```

But this is not working. I am not sure of the error but I am trying to generate the same code as mentioned in the website.

Also for the omega

```
omega = ListInterpolation[Table[(v[[i, j]] - v[[i - 1, j]])/dx - (u[[i, j]]-  u[[i, j - 1]])/ dx, 
  {i, 2, n - 1}, {j, 2, n - 1}], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
  ContourPlot[omega[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> All, ContourShading -> False, Contours -> Range[-14, 7],
  ContourStyle -> Table[{Hue[2 (1 - x)/3]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/21}]]
```

But this is not working as well.

Here is the initial data:

[u.dat & v.dat](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2zqILhKX1cLfkNqMU9yM3liR0M5emRiRnlOU3VLQ1BsRlpnV21Ca0gwU0RvcWsxTVZPR1k&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, the code you found isn't a good example of coding in *Mathematica*. I think the following 3 lines are enough for you:

```
ListStreamPlot[Transpose[{u, v}, {3, 1, 2}], DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
curl = Most /@ Differences@v - Most@Differences[u, {0, 1}];
ListContourPlot@LowpassFilter[curl, 1]
```

[image]
[image]

You may also want to try `ListDensityPlot`:

```
ListDensityPlot[LowpassFilter[curl, 1], ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]
```

[image]

---

OK, I forgot about `ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot`:

```
ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot[Transpose[{u, v}, {3, 1, 2}], 
 ColorFunction -> "RoseColors", DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
(* The following piece of code produces the same graph. *)
(*
{fu, fv} = ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}] & /@ {u, v}
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{fu[x, y], fv[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "RoseColors"]
*)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use LineIntegralConvolutionplot. 
The u and v are discrete values and  using the function Interpolation, the discrete solution can be converted into a black-box continuous function.

Something like : http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/09/using-mathematica-to-simulate-and-visualize-fluid-flow-in-a-box/

I will be trying to use this method and will post the code if I am able to run it.

Comment: @user11948 Code added, have a look.

Comment: If I wish to evaluate stream-function using trapezoidal rule and perform integration u*dy over the complete domain, is there a mathematica inbuilt function to evaluate it or I need to run a loop. 

Thanks

Comment: @user11948 Simply use `Mean@(Most@# + Rest@#)/2 &@u`. You can also try the combination of `Interpolation` and `NIntegrate` if you're not insist on trapezoidal rule. Well… I really suggest you to set more effort on learning the basic of _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 3):

The following part is incorrect, and redundant anyway:

```
\[Psi]= \[Integral]u dx= \[Integral]v dy
\[Omega]= \[PartialD]v/dx-\[PartialD]u/dy
```

Otherwise, the code you copied has only one major problem, in the definition of `n`. If you try to execute it, you get `Do::iterb: Iterator {j,2,n-1} does not have appropriate bounds. >>` which suggests where the problem might lie. In fact, n is defined as the output of Dimensions, so it is a list and not a number as defined. You can fix that by using:

```
n = First@Dimensions[u, 1];
```

instead of your definition.

Once you do that, all the rest works as intended:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But these results are not correct. 
If you see the link attached, the streamline plot and vorticity plot looks totally different. 
One reason might be my velocity vector field is incorrect but i have cross verified it with existing literature and my velocity data is correct

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to take that up with the original author of the code then. I know nothing about computational fluid dynamics. One thing I *can* suggest, however, is to check whether the explicit values chosen by the original author for contour levels etc are still relevant to your results.

Comment: @MacroB : 
So is it possible to perform the integration on discrete values of u and v to evaluate streamlines? 
Is there any other way to run integration in mathematica. 
I can run this using Numerical methods but then I need to use finite difference and in order to check for the convergence , it will take lot of time. 
And most importantly I appreciate you helping you out . Thanks a lot for your time